# Which is Better? Keep on writing to a file or creating a StringBuilder object and write to a file?

Tags: file-io, stringbuilder

I have written an application which extracts excel data and creates SQL CREATE and INSERT statements out of it. Right now I am using a StringBuilder in which I keep on appending statements after reading and extracting data and finally write it down to a file. Another option would be keep on writing to file as I read but it would be costly because of so many write to disc operations. So I wanted to know whether my thought approach is correct or not and should I continue using the StringBuilder to write to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should continue using the `StringBuilder`. I experimented with similar applications recently, and writing to a file after each statement you produce is incredibly slow.

Of course, if you have a large number of statements (I would say >100k, but it depends on the size of each statement), you'd probably want to dump the `StringBuilder` into a file after each X statements to avoid using too much memory. X would depend on the size of each SQL statement.

BTW, you didn't specify which DB you are using, but if you are using MySQL, you should create a single INSERT statement for inserting multiple rows. It would work much faster than a single statement for each row (for example - `INSERT INTO TableName VALUES (x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2),...,(xn,yn,zn);`);

Comment: Thanks Eran for the suggestion. I am using derby database. Good thing you pointed out. I will have to check whether it accepts a single statement for each row. If it does, I will change accordingly.

Comment: I don't think it's correct imply that `StringBuilder` is always the best approach to take. E.g. you may want to write out your buffers more than once per operation to avoid memory bloat or to avoid starving whatever is consuming the output (although the latter probably doesn't apply here).

Comment: @RJFalconer It's a good point. The OP didn't say how many statements we are talking about, and if the number is very high, it would make sense to limit the size of the StringBuilder and flush it to the disk. I updated the answer.

Comment: It is going to be around 10 tables and maximum of 1000 statements not more than that. @RJFalconer  I understand your point that if its gonna be a huge file, I should keep milestones and write it after that avoiding cache excess usage. What did you mean by once per operation?

Comment: @VivinRaj This is a small number of statements, so assuming the size of a single statement isn't too big, you should be fine with collecting all statements in a single StringBuilder and dumping them to the file at the end.

Comment: @VivinRaj by "operation" I meant "each invocation of the relevant code", i.e. each instance of you running your "generate SQL code" method. I don't imagine file size will be much of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Neither method is wrong, but I would use a hybrid of both methods. The write chunk size would depend on the importance of your data. If it's something that is not easily recoverable and is important, you want to write smaller chunks. If it is less important and can be recovered easily, use a larger chunk size.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I think that the size and importance is also an important thing to consider. Good suggestion